# libpcre.so could not read symbols : Apache 2.4 install

Tags: pcre, apache2.4

Hi I am trying to install 2.4 on linux: 
    Linux el5 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I am getting an error after 'make install':

```
**/usr/local/lib/libpcre.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [httpd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/myapp/httpd-2.4.7'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

My config.nice that I am executing:

```
CFLAGS="-m32"; export CFLAGS
LDFLAGS="-m32"; export LDFLAGS
"./configure" \
"--prefix=/opt/myapp/apache2.4" \
"--with-mpm=worker" \
"--enable-static-support" \
"--enable-ssl=static" \
"--enable-modules=most" \
"--disable-authndbd" \
"--disable-authn-dbm" \
"--disable-dbd" \
"--enable-static-logresolve" \
"--enable-static-rotatelogs" \
"--enable-proxy=static" \
"--enable-proxyconnect=static" \
"--enable-proxy-ftp=static" \
"--enable-proxy-http=static" \
"--enable-rewrite=static" \
"--enable-so=static" \
"--with-ssl=/opt/myapp/apache2.4/openssl" \
"--host=x86_32-unknown-linux-gnu" \
"host_alias=x86_32-unknown-linux-gnu" \
"CFLAGS=-m32" \
"LDFLAGS=-m32" \
"--with-included-apr" \
"--with-pcre=/usr/local" \
"$@"
```

ldd:
        ldd /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b2ce3b82000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003e1c800000)

file:
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Jan 31 15:20 /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so -> libpcre.so.1.2.1

I am not able to figure out how to get read of "could not read symbols". I have configured pcre8.34 in /lib/local. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you get 32 bit PCRE compiling? If so, how did you get it to pick up the CFLAGS environment variable?

Comment: The problem was with 32bit C compiler. Installing glibc-devel.i386 resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a 32-bit (-m32 flag) version of Apache. Try either to install the 64-bit version or to install a 32-bit version of libpcre.

Comment: I ran ./configure --enable-pcre32 and it created 32bit libs for PCRE in /usr/local/bin. Still 'make' for apache is fetching /usr/local/lib/libpcre.so and throwing same error again. Do I need to remove these first so that it pics /usr/local/lib/libpcre32.so?

Comment: You probably have a ./configure option like --with-pcre= and you should use it to indicate the full path to your 32-bit version of libpcre. BTW Why do you want to have a 32-bit version of Apache ?

Comment: Well, I have a apache 2.2 32bit already installed and want to upgrade it to 2.4. But before I upgrade the existing one, I want to test the fresh installation of 2.4. I made the changes the way you mentioned, but the 'make' looks for pcre-config file and not for libpcre.so... Once pcre-config is executed it sets the correct libraries. Now, it looks like pcre-config is not picking 32bit lib correctly, which it should since CFLAG=-m32